# Need a solution to sent i2c data long distance (prefereably convert to CAN)

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, i2c, can

Is there any IC available that can read I2C data from a sensor and convert to CAN. I was looking for a low-cost solution to reading i2c data and putting it on a CAN bus. Reading i2c with a microcontroller and converting to CAN would be an option, but the cost is the primary factor.

Comment: How about an STM32F103? It has CAN and I2C and should fit your needs. You can take the BLUEPILL, if you don't want to design your own PCB, that will cost only around 3$ and then you need a CAN Tranceiver, that will maybe cost again 1-2$.

Comment: how about the LIN bus? works using 12volts (designed to run on car battery)

Comment: Haven't through about LIN. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

THe simplest/cheapest option would be a uProcessor with a CAN controller, plus a CAN transceiver chip (plus additional components to enable it to work)

STM32F103RBT6 (£4.17 in 100off) + SN65HVD230D ( £1.53 in 100off)

YOu need something that can interface to I2C and can communicate via CAN

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about this. The challenge if that there are multiple sensors which output data on I2c separated by large distance. If we use a uC for each sensor, the cost would be a problem. I was thinking of a way to use only one uC which pulls data from all the sensors and then puts it in the CAN bus

Answer (score 1):

Just use I2C to differential I2C converters on both ends

For example: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCA9615.pdf